# What does "alight on his feet" mean?

Tags: meaning

In Oxford Dictionary, under 'alight', it says:

> 1. on fire
>
> •A cigarette set the dry grass alight.
>
> 2. (formal) (of faces or eyes) showing a feeling of happiness or excitement
>
> •The children’s faces were alight with enthusiasm.

.................................................

What does "alight on his feet" mean in this sentence?

> It's a relieve that the soccer player was alight on his feet.

Comment: There are several errors. "It's a relief that the soccer player was light on his feet." reads correctly. Light on his feet would mean he is agile and quick.

Comment: or still upright on his feet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several other answers that are misunderstanding the meaning of OP's sentence.

As I stated in my comment, there are two errors here. Alight is not correct. Alight has a totally different meaning. Relieve is not correct. Correcting the sentence results in:

"It's a relief that the soccer player was light on his feet."

Even this sounds a little awkward to me.

Light-footed is an adjective meaning "moving gracefully and nimbly", per Merriam-Webster. A clear, concise rewriting of the sentence results in:

"It's a relief the soccer player is light-footed."